# Hover over button, strikethrough text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to edit my code so, that if I hover over the delete button, the text gets a strikethrough-line, just like the css option `text-decoration: line-through` does. 
**EDIT:
I'm trying to have the Text** *"Creating this basic TODO Website"* **with a strikethrough, when hovering over the delete button**

Is there a way to achieve this, without using JS, or do I need to use JS? (I'm currently using Bootstrap4)

The Code part is:

```html
<tr>
  <th scope="row">3</th>
  <td class="text-justify">Creating this basic TODO Website</td>
  <td>14/05/2020</td>
  <td>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%;" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">10%</div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit" onclick="window.location.href='Edit.html' ;">
        <i class="material-icons">create</i>
     </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
        <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I tried to add to css:

td:last-child:hover ~ td{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
So that the text "Creating this basic TODO Website" gets the text-decoration, but that doesn't work, like other CSS parent/sibling combinations I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand your problem. The problem is there is no "previous sibling" or "parent" selector in css. But I think a little bit tricky dom modification, and pure css, you can achive your goal.

```css
table tr {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

table tr td:hover+td+td+td+td.your-text {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
     <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
          <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit" onclick="window.location.href='Edit.html' ;">
          <i class="material-icons">create</i>
       </button>
     </td>
    <td>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%;" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">10%</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>14/05/2020</td>
    <td class="text-justify your-text">Creating this basic TODO Website</td>
    <th scope="row">3</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Explanation: The td-s are reversed, and css flexbox make re-reverse order. So it visible as normal order, but it is important: in the dom, it is reversed. After that you can use next element selector (`+`) more than once times. And the last trick: I split the buttons cell into two parts to access to delete button's cell exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with CSS

```
i:hover {
     text-decoration: line-through;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I want to make a line through the text "Creating this basic TODO Website", not through the "delete" text

Answer (score 1):

When you use bootstrap X, you can still use CSS:

```css
button.not-available:hover, button.not-available i:hover {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<button class="not-available">
    <i>create</i>
</button>
<button>
    <i>delete</i>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I want to make a line through the text "Creating this basic TODO Website", not through the "delete" text

Comment: @ElMagico, I modify the code block, to separate each button. Try it!